# UK visitor visa expired

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

I am a medical doctor. I have already taken 2 exams in the UK to work as a doctor there. I just have one more exam to take. I hold a visitor visa, which expires on 29/12/2017. However, I have booked the exam date on 23/01/2018.

I'd like to ask if it is possible to apply for a new visitor visa before my old one expires. Because the dates are quite close to each other as I don't want to miss the exam.

What can be the best option for my situation?

Comment: How long have you spent in the UK on the current visa? It can affect your chances of getting a new visa if it looks like you are using one after another to establish residence in the UK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Source: UKVI email followed up with personal experience.

> If the application is granted and the applicant already has entry clearance
>   beyond the start date of their new visa, they should be told that the
>   extant leave will be cancelled and no refund issued.
>
> The entry clearance should be crossed out by writing “Recommend cancel
>   without prejudice” diagonally across the redundant visa (in red ink),
>   make a note in Proviso and then grant fresh entry clearance in the same
>   passport as the previous leave.

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/extant-leave-ecb22/extant-leave-ecb22

In my case, the new visa was in a new passport and no note was made across the old one.

Comment: Thank you very much! In your opinion, do you think it may be better solution if I apply for a new visa on the day after my old one expires?

Comment: @Mia yes. There is enough time.